# Proteger conteúdo de arquivos php?

Tags: php, pdo, aplicação-web, segurança

Não sei se estou fazendo certo, porém possuo um arquivo chamado setting.php em meu projeto, mas não estou certo de que ele está protegido pois ele contém as informações de login do admin do cpanel, logo se alguém tiver acesso a ele terá acessado a todos os arquivos e até mesmo ao DB, devo mudar alguma permissão nesse arquivo? ou apenas algo como:

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',0);
function conectar(){
    try{
        $pdo=new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testlogin","root","");
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $pdo;
}
```

Seria o suficiente?

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem o post, mas até onde vi o arquivo de configuração nesse estilo que apresentei seria o ideal então?